# RefineryCMS - show.html.erb can't be overridden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I am running refinerycms 1.0.8 and rails 3.0.10.
I have the following piece of code in app/views/pages/show.html.erb

```
<div id="startpageheader">
  <%= raw @page.content_for(:startpageheader) %>
</div>
<section id='body_content'>
  <%=raw @page.content_for(:body) %>
</section>
```

If I run this local in development mode, I get the following (desired) output:

```
<section id='page'>
  <div id="startpageheader">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <section id='body_content'>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

But as soon as I start this in production mode, I get the following:

```
<section id='page'>
  <section id='body_content' class='no_body_content_right'>
    <h1 id='body_content_title'>Home</h1>
    <section id='body_content_left'><div class='inner'><p>...</p></div></section>
    <section id='startpageheader'><div class='inner'><p>...</p></div></section>
  </section>
</section>
```

So, the page parts are shown, but in a wrong view. I tried to hunt this down in the production logs, but I ended up nowhere.
Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and, of course, it was my own fault. For whatever reason I managed it somehow to delete the first Page (Home) from the pages-menu. So, back then, I created a new one, which wasn't the actual homepage but just a normal page. 
When I modified the show view `show.html.erb` for the pages, the changes were shown, of course. But in production, the original homepage wasn't deleted and therefore changes in `show.html.erb` didn't show up, since the first view responds to `home.html.erb`.
Thanks everybody who tried to help me and sorry for the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you do not have data populated in your production database.

I dont have refinery's source in front of me right now but one of the things it does is give "no_body_content_right" if the right panel doesn't have any data. It makes it pretty helpful when styling it later.

Check your page in the admin, populate the data if it's missing and let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Also thanks for the answer, but that's not the problem. My database is migrated (for production) and also populated. The :body_content_right is supposed to be empty. The contents for Body and startpageheader are also both showing up, just not in the right place. Apparently, Refinery uses the standard show.html.erb and ignores my overridden file.

Comment: @klaffenboeck i've overridden pretty much every view they have (for cyberstride.net) and I didn't run into a problem where it wasn't picking up the right view.

Comment: thanks again. May I just ask really quit, which version of rails and refinery you are using? Very much appreciated.

Comment: @klaffenboeck i honestly can't recall, 3.1 i believe though.

Comment: @klaffenboeck check this file out (you'll likely want to override it), it could be causing your issues: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/core/app/views/refinery/_content_page.html.erb

Comment: Thank you once more. Problem is, I am running the latest stable version 1.0.8 which requires Rails 3.0.x (in my case 3.0.10)

Comment: @klaffenboeck np man, my advise at this point is to post on the usergroup. http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/topics

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your production database.

If you look at `shared/_content_page.html.erb` you can see that you get `<section id='body_content' class='no_body_content_right'>` ..etc. when you don't pass in sections to be yielded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the database is migrated and populated in production. I didn't think about checking the source for shared/_content_page.html.erb, so thanks for that hint. Nonetheless, this is totally correct, since the :side_body doesn't exist in my application (I deleted it) and therefore there is nothing to load for :body_content_right

Comment: Go into your /refinery go to settings, go to "Default Page Parts" and remove `--sidebody` as that's probably what is causing you problems.  It's trying to render a page part you are no longer wanting.

Comment: I already removed that part. The point is, that shared/_content_page.html.erb shouldn't be loaded at all, since I override show.html.erb original content <%= render :partial => "/shared/content_page" %> with the one I mention in my post.